# Create BooleanBinding binded with List/ObstableList values

Tags: javafx, binding, observable

I'm trying to create `BooleanBinding` which is a binded with `Button#disableProperty()`. My purpose is to  enable/disable the OK button when changing a `TextField` from a dynamically created list of panels.

This is the initialization of the list of panels (propertiesList)

```
<DialogPane prefWidth="900" prefHeight="600" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.172-ea" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">

    <fx:define>
        <FXCollections fx:id="propertiesList" fx:factory="observableArrayList">
            <DatabasePane name="База данни"/>
            <DatabasePane name="База данни 2"/>
        </FXCollections>
    </fx:define>

    ....

    <buttonTypes>
        <ButtonType fx:id="okButtonType" buttonData="OK_DONE" text="Готово" />
        <ButtonType buttonData="CANCEL_CLOSE" text="Затвори" />
    </buttonTypes>

</DialogPane>
```

Each `DatabasePane` contains `BooleanProperty` named `change` and corresponding getters and setters.

In the controller, I create a `BooleanProperty` collection from the properties of the panels added in `propertiesList`

```
List<BooleanProperty> list = propertiesList.stream()
    .map(pane -> pane.changeProperty())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

BooleanBinding change = Bindings.createBooleanBinding(() -> true, (BooleanProperty[]) list.toArray());

Button button = (Button) dialogPane.lookupButton(okButtonType);
button.disableProperty().bind(change.not());
```

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to class [Ljavafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty; ([Ljava.lang.Object; is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; [Ljavafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty; is in module javafx.base of loader 'app')
```

If I use `ObservableList` there are no errors, but only changes are made to the list itself

```
ObservableList<BooleanProperty> list = propertiesList.stream()
    .map(pane -> pane.changeProperty())
    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(() -> FXCollections.observableArrayList()));

BooleanBinding change = Bindings.createBooleanBinding(() -> true, list);

Button button = (Button) dialogPane.lookupButton(okButtonType);
button.disableProperty().bind(change.not());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`List.toArray()` returns an `Object[]` array not an `BooleanProperty[]` array, but you cast the object array to `BooleanProperty` here:

```
(BooleanProperty[]) list.toArray()
```

I recommend using [`Stream`'s `toArray` method taking a `IntFunction`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#toArray-java.util.function.IntFunction-):

```
Observable[] dependencies = propertiesList.stream()
                                          .map(DatabasePane::changeProperty)
                                          .toArray(Observable[]::new);

BooleanBinding change = Bindings.createBooleanBinding(() -> true, dependencies);
```

Unless you change the `Callable<Boolean>` to something more meaningfull though, you could leave out the dependencies as well, since the binding never contains a value but `true`.

---

```
BooleanBinding change = Bindings.createBooleanBinding(() -> true, list);
```

does not work, since the list itself implements `Observable` so you're passing a array containing only the list to the varargs parameter, i.e. it's equivalent to

```
BooleanBinding change = Bindings.createBooleanBinding(() -> true, new Observable []{ list });
```

and the only `InvalidationListener` that is added is added to the list itself, not to it's contents.

Comment: Your solution is perfect. What I have given is just an example, so we've made it return the true. 10x